# Can we conclude that the mean curvature operator is elliptic in a coordinate-free way?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

It is well known that the mean curvature operator $H$ on surface immersions is elliptic, as can be seen through a straightforward computation after writing an immersion $r$ (locally) as a graph.

Is it possible to conclude ellipticity without going to local coordinates like this?  In particular, by choosing a smooth function $\varphi$ on the surface and a normal vector $N$, it follows from linearizing $H$ around $\varphi N$ that $$L_\varphi H = \Delta \varphi + |h|^2\varphi,$$ 
where $|h|^2$ is the norm of the second fundamental form), so can we immediately say that the top-order part of this is a Laplace-Beltrami operator and hence conclude ellipticity?  An answer and/or a reference would be helpful -- I do not know much about the classification of PDEs on manifolds.

Comment: Yes. Ellipticity is a property of the symbol of the operator — i.e., depends only on the highest-order terms.

Comment: Thanks, Ted. I suspected as much, but for some reason I could not find (or maybe could not understand) a clear answer to this.